# How should I say "3 2 1 go!" in German?

Tags: translation, english-to-german

How should I say "3 2 1 go!" in German? For example, in a race, start running after the countdown ends.

Answer (score 28):

As an equivalent to "go", there's the adverb [los](https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/los_Aufforderung_locker). It basically is a request to start something, to hurry up, to get going etc.

> Los, beeil Dich!
> Come one, hurry up!

In a race, "los" can be used in multiple ways, for example

> Drei, zwei, eins, los!
> Three, two, one, go!

or in the opposite direction

> Eins, zwei, drei, los!

The latter is similar to the English "on the count of three". With this variation, the "three" is often used as the "go" signal, omitting an explicit "go": "Eins, zwei, *drei*!"

You can also use a more "race specific" lingo, that you may encounter in official races:

> Auf die Plätze. Fertig. Los!
> On your marks. Ready. Go!

or similar

> Achtung. Fertig. Los!
> Attention. Ready. Go!

Comment: Los is not an adverb. It is the imperative form of the verb "losen" which means to loosen or release a thing.

Comment: *the verb "losen" which means to loosen or release a thing* ← you're thinking of **lösen** (imperative would be *lös(e)*).

Comment: @Brendon: [DWDS](https://www.dwds.de/wb/los) does not share your view.

Comment: Indeed, those pesky dots on the Ö are not of decorative nature, even if Motörhead or Blue Öyster Cult make it seem so ;) There is a word "(aus)losen", i.e. to cast lots, which doesn't fit here. And if you said "Los!" as imperative, that also sounds rather informal, like there should be an apostrophe at the end. "Lose!" it would be, when speaking to one person you are on a first name basis with. Or "Löse" in the case of what you meant, "Löst!" in plural. Also informal, which would be weird in this context. Los feels like the beginning of "loslaufen!" but short & pragmatic for the purpose.

Comment: The last two are the idiomatic uses. You could make that clearer.

Comment: @Peter-ReinstateMonica I wouldn't call those versions _the_ idiomatic uses necessarily, but rather a more formal or "official" use. I'd place them more in official races where prize money, ranking points or the like are in play, or where there might be formal protests if the race management didn't do things correctly. The same goes for the English versions like "On your marks. Ready. Go!", while the question explicitly asked about "Three two one go!". I edited the answer to make that more clear.

Answer (score 2):

Normally they will say: Auf die Plätze. Fertig. Los!

Comment: Welcomto to German SE. You may not have noted, that is is already covered in the top-voted answer.  In that case a new answer is better received, if it gives some additional emphasis, highlight or background.

Comment: sounds more appropriate to the situation. Danke